# Updating UI using ViewModel and DataBinding

Tags: android-databinding, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel, android-livedata

I am trying to learn ViewModel in android, in my first phase of learning I am trying to update UI (TextView) by using ViewModel and DataBinding. In ViewModel, I have an AsyncTask callback and it will invoke REST API call. I am getting the response from API call but the value in textview is not getting updated.

my ViewModel class:

```java
public class ViewModelData extends ViewModel {

    private MutableLiveData<UserData> users;

    public LiveData<UserData> getUsers() {
        if (users == null) {
            users = new MutableLiveData<UserData>();
            loadUsers();
        }

        return users;
    }

    public void loadUsers() {
        ListTask listTask =new ListTask (taskHandler);
        listTask .execute();

    }

    public Handler taskHandler= new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {


            UserData  userData = (UserData) msg.obj;
        
            users.setValue(userData);
        }
    };
}
```

and my MainActivity class:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LifecycleOwner {
    private LifecycleRegistry mLifecycleRegistry;
    private TextView fName;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        fName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_name);
        mLifecycleRegistry = new LifecycleRegistry(this);
        mLifecycleRegistry.markState(Lifecycle.State.CREATED);
        ViewModelData model = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ViewModelData.class);
        model.getUsers().observe(this, new Observer<UserData>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable UserData userData) {
                Log.d("data"," =  - - - - ="+userData.getFirstName());

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public Lifecycle getLifecycle() {
        return mLifecycleRegistry;
    }
}
```

and my data class:

```java
public class UserData extends BaseObservable{
    private String firstName ;
@Bindable
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.firstName);
    }
}
```

and layout file

```xml
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <data>
        <import type="android.view.View" />
        <variable name="data" type="com.cgi.viewmodelexample.UserData"/>
    </data>
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/activity_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.cgi.viewmodelexample.MainActivity">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{data.firstName}"
            android:id="@+id/text_name"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: yes.. i have done this in Main Class

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I suggest to follow next basic principles:

- don't overload data objects by business or presentation logic
- only view model required to obtain data in presentation layer
- view model should expose only *ready to use* data to presentation layer
- (optional) background task should expose `LiveData` to deliver data

Implementation notes:

- `firstName` is read only on view
- `lastName` is editable on view
- `loadUser()` is not threadsafe
- we have error message when call `save()` method until data is not loaded

#### Don't overload data objects by business or presentation logic

Suppose, we have `UserData` object with first and last name. So, getters it's (usually) all what we need:

```
public class UserData {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public UserData(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
}
```

#### Only view model required to obtain data in presentation

To follow this suggestion we should to use only view model in data binding layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.vmtestapplication.MainActivity">

    <data>

        <import type="android.view.View" />

        <!-- Only view model required -->
        <variable
            name="vm"
            type="com.example.vmtestapplication.UserDataViewModel" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- Primitive error message -->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{vm.error}"
            android:visibility="@{vm.error == null ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE}"/>

        <!-- Read only field (only `@`) -->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{vm.firstName}" />

        <!-- Two-way data binding (`@=`) -->
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@={vm.lastName}" />

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

*Note: you can use a few view models in one layout, but not raw data*

#### View model should expose only ready to use data to presentation

This mean, you shouldn't to expose *complex data objects* (`UserData` in our case) directly from view model. Preferable to expose privative types which view can use *as-is*. In example below we don't need to hold `UserData` object because it used only to loading *grouped* data. We, probably, need to create `UserData` to save it but it depends on your repository implementation.

```
public class UserDataViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private ListTask loadTask;

    private final MutableLiveData<String> firstName = new MediatorLiveData<>();
    private final MutableLiveData<String> lastName = new MediatorLiveData<>();
    private final MutableLiveData<String> error = new MutableLiveData<>();

    /**
     * Expose LiveData if you do not use two-way data binding
     */
    public LiveData<String> getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    /**
     * Expose MutableLiveData to use two-way data binding
     */
    public MutableLiveData<String> getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public LiveData<String> getError() {
        return error;
    }

    @MainThread
    public void loadUser(String userId) {
        // cancel previous running task
        cancelLoadTask();
        loadTask = new ListTask();
        Observer<UserData> observer = new Observer<UserData>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable UserData userData) {
                // transform and deliver data to observers
                firstName.setValue(userData == null? null : userData.getFirstName());
                lastName.setValue(userData == null? null : userData.getLastName());
                // remove subscription on complete
                loadTask.getUserData().removeObserver(this);
            }
        };
        // it can be replaced to observe() if LifeCycleOwner is passed as argument
        loadTask.getUserData().observeForever(observer);
        // start loading task
        loadTask.execute(userId);
    }

    public void save() {
        // clear previous error message
        error.setValue(null);
        String fName = firstName.getValue(), lName = lastName.getValue();
        // validate data (in background)
        if (fName == null || lName == null) {
            error.setValue("Opps! Data is invalid");
            return;
        }
        // create and save object
        UserData newData = new UserData(fName, lName);
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCleared() {
        super.onCleared();
        cancelLoadTask();
    }

    private void cancelLoadTask() {
        if (loadTask != null)
            loadTask.cancel(true);
        loadTask = null;
    }
}
```

#### Background task should expose `LiveData` to deliver data

```
public class ListTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, UserData> {

    private final MutableLiveData<UserData> data= new MediatorLiveData<>();

    public LiveData<UserData> getUserData() {
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(UserData userData) {
        data.setValue(userData);
    }

    @Override
    protected UserData doInBackground(String[] userId) {
        // some id validations
        return loadRemoiteUser(userId[0]);
    }
}
```

---

#### MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private UserDataViewModel viewModel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // get view model
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(UserDataViewModel.class);
        // create binding
        ActivityMainBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
        // set view model to data binding
        binding.setVm(viewModel);
        // don't forget to set LifecycleOwner to data binding
        binding.setLifecycleOwner(this);

        // start user loading (if necessary)
        viewModel.loadUser("user_id");
        // ...
    }
}
```

*PS: try to use RxJava library instead of `AsyncTask` to perform background work.*

Comment: binding.setLifecycleOwner(this); i am not able to use this Method, is there any alternative method is available and and i am getting data Binding error too while doing rebuild (its thorws DataBinding is exist.).

Comment: @karthikselvaraj which version of Android Studio and gradle plugin do you use? Can you post original error message or full stack trace?

Comment: Wow, the comment `Expose MutableLiveData to use two-way data binding` was really helpful!! Thanks!

Comment: What would be the best recommendation for an app that has user authentication and then showing bookings by the user. So Login/Signup pages will have to interact with UserRepo and Dashboard page has to interact with UserRepo and BookingsRepo, also Profile page just need to deals with UserRepo?

Comment: Also, I have seen posts where they have something like fun onLoginClick(view: View){} inside viewmodel and then bind it with XML. But somewhere else I read that View should never be passed to ViewModel. I am confused!

Comment: @SuyashDixit with `onLoginClick(view: View){}` you can use [method reference binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions#method_references) instead of [listener binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions#listener_bindings). It makes your binding code shorter but no more. You still shouldn't store links of view inside of view model. Moreover, this view argument usually ignored

Answer (score 0):

You'll require to notify observer when you set value like this :

```
public class UserData extends BaseObservable{
private String firstName ;
@Bindable
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR.firstName) // call like this
}
}
```

Comment: because of data binding, you've set **UserData** as variable in xml. so any changes related to **UserData** will reflect to **UI through DataBinding**.

Answer (score 0):

If you want binding layout to work then you have to set your view in binding way. Also set data in binding class.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LifecycleOwner {
    ActivityMainBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
        ...
        ViewModelData model = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ViewModelData.class);
        ...
        binding.setData(model.getUsers());
    }
}
```

Comment: can you explain little bit more ?  i have changed in layout file and bind the viewModel in mainclass (like what you mentioned in code)  even though i didn't get this.

Comment: Are you setting `notifyPropertyChanged` in `setFirstName()`

Comment: yes, i have used "  notifyPropertyChanged(BR.firstName);"

Comment: I could only see above issue in your code, now it should work as expected. How are you setting data when response come?

Comment: i will receive the data in handler and by using setvalue will set data(all this things done in ViewModel class). now i am getting an compile time error while doing binding "binding.setData(model.getUsers());" . i tried smae what you metioned in your code.